# Mockito how to unit test a static method which has many objects to be mocked inside

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I have to unit test a static method which looks like this:

```
public static boolean someProcess(List<String> arg1, Properties props, String[] arg3, String arg4, String arg5) throws Exception {
    boolean success = false;
    Job1 job1 = new Job1(arg3, props.getProperty("prop1"), props.getProperty("prop2"), arg1.get(0), arg4, "asdf", arg5);

    if(doJobAndCheckStatus(arg1, job1)) {
        String someId = job1.someId;
        Job2 job2 = new Job2(arg3, someId, arg4, arg5);

        if(doJobAndCheckStatus(arg1, job2)) {
            Job3 job3 = new Job3(arg3, someId, arg4, arg5);

            if(doJobAndCheckStatus(arg1, job3)) {
                String id2 = job3.id2;
                Job4 job4 = new Job4(arg3, id2, props.getProperty("prop3"), arg4, arg5);

                if(doJobAndCheckStatus(arg1, job4)) {
                    String id3 = job4.id3;
                    Job5 job5 = new job5(arg3, id3, arg4, arg5, props.getProperty("prop4"));

                    if(doJobAndCheckStatus(arg1, job5)) {
                        success = jobCompletedSuccessfully(arg1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return success;
}

public static boolean doJobAndCheckStatus(List<String> arg1, JobParent job) {
    job.processJob();
    ....
}
```

As shown above, in this static method, there are 5 JobX classes to initialize. All these Job classes are complex objects which will connect to external systems.

My idea of unit testing this method is:

1. Mock all the JobX classes which are used in the someProcess method.
2. Configure all the mocked classes to return the status of "success" when their processJob methods are called.
3. This someProcess method should return true if every job is completed successfully

My questions are:

1. Does my idea make sense at all? What's there to test for this
   particular method at all?
2. Best way to test this method? How to get all the mocked JobX classes into effect?

Any enlightenment will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Nicole, have a look at [my article on mocking object creation](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation) - it may give you some ideas that you can use here.

Comment: Hi thank you Dawood, I read your article, it's informative. There is another problem here. The method under tests are static methods and I cannot modify those public methods, cannot refactor them from static to non static. How to test such static methods then?

Comment: You don't need to make them non static. But you really should refactor the creation of those objects into separate static methods. Or you can use non static methods of a helper class, but have a static instance of that class.